# How to edit the content of li when a button is clicked JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
function addDeleteEvents(){
  var tasks = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
   for (var index = 0; index <tasks.length; index++){
        tasks[index].addEventListener("click", function(){
         this.classList.toggle("active");
      });
      tasks[index].querySelector("#dlt").addEventListener("click",
      function(){
         this.closest(".task").remove();
      });
      tasks[index].querySelector("#edt").addEventListener("click",
      function(){
        //i want to edit tasks[i] when button with id #edt is clicked
      });
   }
}
```

this code is part of a todo app , the todo works as li for each task
I want to edit tasks[i] when button with id #edt is clicked.

Comment: what do you mean "edit"? show your HTML

Comment: Add an event listener for the click of the event and in that callback function create an input element or text area element along with an apply button, that will allow you to type your edit into and then apply your change.

Comment: code should go in the question

Comment: @Bravo https://codepen.io/aromalsanthosh/pen/NWjZoQR heres the code